# SQL Query to group records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with the following columns:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| Client    Flow,   Trade Date, RIC Code, BuySell |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| Client A  Manual  29/3/13     AAPL.O      B     |
| Client A  DMA     29/3/13     AAPL.O      S     |
| Client C  DMA     28/3/13     AAPL.O      B     |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

(Table amended to clarify that CLient A traded on both flows and hence should be reported)

I need to get a view which client has traded the same RIC Code on the same Trade Date BUT across different flows.

So for the above I would expect to see something like:

```
Client A, AAPL.0, 29/3/13, 2
```

2 as in two trades a across two different flows and it being a buy AND sell (but actually it would be ok to just see a Buy OR a Sell across different flows for now).

The table above is already the result of a group by from a wider table. I can't think of a good way of doing this, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your sample data has a different client on every row?

Comment: You just need 4 columns in Output and as u said RIC code will be same for a day can differ two days, do you want to group this at weekly or monthly basis, in that case which RIC code do you need ??????

Comment: Please clarify your expected result set and the entry. Here is a start point. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/828c6/8. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Gidil for editing so nicely!

Comment: Each line contains trades done by a client on a date for a particular stock on a particular trade flow. I basically need to find clients that trade the same day, the same instrument and present this in a format a human can read. I've done this in Excel using Pivots but no good way of just showing the scenarios where on a single day say Client A traded AAPL.O on both DMA and Manual.

Comment: @Anda in your sample code client B and C should not be included in the results as they did not trade ACROSS flows.

Comment: Seems a self join is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need a self join.

You can try :

```
SELECT t.Client, t.RICCode, t.TradeDate, COUNT(t.Flow) AS CNT 
FROM 
(
    SELECT a.Client, a.RICCode, a.TradeDate, a.FLow
    FROM trades a 
    INNER JOIN trades b ON a.Client = b.Client AND a.RICCode = b.RICCode AND a.TradeDate = b.TradeDate AND a.Flow <> b.Flow
    GROUP BY a.Client, a.RICCode, a.TradeDate, a.Flow
) AS t 
GROUP BY Client, RICCode, TradeDate;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01055/2.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ignore flow then this might do the trick

```
SELECT client, [trade date], [ric code], Count(client)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY client, [trade date], [ric code];
```